# Update Column based on SELECT with Parameter coming from UPDATE

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, sql

I want to do something like this.

```
UPDATE tbl_states AS ts
SET    tbl_states.country_id = (SELECT tbl_countries.country_id
                                FROM   tbl_states ts1
                                       JOIN tbl_countries
                                         ON tbl_countries.country_id_id =
                                            ts1.country_id
                                WHERE  ts1.country_id_id = ts.country_id_id)
```

I want to update **old** `country_id` which came from different database to **new** `country_id` based on new primary keys inserted on the new database. To give you an idea here is the schema.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_countries](
    [country_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [country_id_id] [int] NULL,
    [country_name] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

`country_id_id` is the **old** `country_id` referenced on the next table I will show you `tbl_states`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_states](
    [state_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [state_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [country_id] [int] NULL,
    [state_abbr] [char](3) NOT NULL)
```

I want to update `country_id` column of this table `tbl_states` to primary column of the table above using the following select statement to get the primary key.

```
SELECT tbl_countries.country_id
FROM   tbl_states_old
       JOIN tbl_countries
         ON tbl_countries.country_id_id = tbl_states_old.country_id
```

Sorry for the title, I don't know what this is called. Could you help me with this?

Comment: +1 I had no idea what to call this either!  Thankfully (sometimes) Google can read minds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE s
    SET country_id = c.country_id
    FROM tbl_states s
        INNER JOIN tbl_countries c
            ON s.country_id = c.country_id_id
```

Comment: shoot, haven't slept yet haha. Thanks!